# Ruby statements, whitespace versus parentheses

Tags: ruby, syntax

### Why are parentheses required in this?

I am looking for a purely syntax related reasoning. This is not a question about what should or not be in ruby for beauty or whatever.

```
not(['a','u','i','o','e'].include? s[0].downcase)
#this third line will error!
not ['a','u','i','o','e'].include? s[0].downcase

#you can also incorrectly represent this as
not['a','u','i','o','e'].include?(s[0].downcase)
#but correctly as this with the higher precedence !
!['a','u','i','o','e'].include?(s[0].downcase)
#but then again incorrectly as
!['a','u','i','o','e'].include? s[0].downcase
```

In general I think the whitespaces with (), {}, ;, \n, and end are oddly difficult to get correct in ruby. It has something to do with precendence. Can someone show me a mapping of where and not these invisible () are when executing the above code.

Comment: What makes you think parenthese are required in this case?

Comment: The interpreter errors out if I don't have parentheses in the ones marked as incorrect.

Comment: On what Ruby version is that?

Comment: ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: While parenthesis are optional with methods, their use allow you to tell the interpreter exactly what you want it to do and when. I recommend their use until you are very familiar with Ruby's parsing.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Only the line starting with `not[` gives me a syntax error. That's not an operator precidence problem, it simply appears that `not[` cannot be parsed by Ruby. `not(` works while `not{` fails as well.